# <img src="/foo/image.jpg"> not working

Tags: html

I have my bar.html file in the same folder as the foo directory, and image.jpg is in foo but

```
<img src="/foo/image.jpg">
```

just displays a broken img link.

I've tried putting image.jpg in the same folder as bar.html and foo and change the html too

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

and that shows image.jpg just fine.

I don't understand what's going on here can someone please help?

Comment: `<img src="foo/image.jpg">`. Forward slash `/` means the root of the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the first slash

```
<img src="foo/image.jpg">
         ^^--Here
```

When you put a forward slash at the beginning then it means that path is not relative but read from the root of the site/server